# How to select Top % in T-SQL without using Top clause?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How to select Top 40% from a table without using the Top clause (or Top percent, the assignment is a little ambiguous) ? This question is for T-SQL, SQL Server 2008. I am not allowed to use Top for my assignment.

Thanks.

This is what I've tried but seems complicated. Isn't there an easier way ?

```
select top (convert (int, (select round (0.4*COUNT(*), 0) from MyTable))) * from MyTable
```

Comment: Your assignment? What have you tried?

Comment: The "what I've tried" contains `TOP`

Comment: The assignment text is kinda ambiguous and doesn't specify If i cannot use Top, refers only to Top n percent. Is code portability the only disadvantage of using Top or are there other disadvantages ?

Comment: The fact that it is non standard is the major disadvantage IMO. You may well find your version performs better and is more accurate than the `NTILE` answers. If the table has 15 rows they will return 8 rather than 6.

Comment: The `PERCENT` option puts a ceiling on the resulting number of rows if it’s not whole. If the result is 330 rows. Filtering 1 percent
gives you 3.3, and then the ceiling of this value is 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A problem with the `NTILE(10)` answers given so far is that if the table has 15 rows they will return 8 rows (53%) rather than the correct number to make up 40% (6).

If the number of rows is not evenly divisible by number of buckets the extra rows all go into the first buckets rather than being evenly distributed.

This alternative (borrows SQL Menace's table) avoids that issue.

```
WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY Score) AS RN,
                COUNT(*) OVER()                     AS Cnt
         FROM   #temp)
SELECT StudentID,
       Score
FROM   CTE
WHERE  RN <= CEILING(0.4 * Cnt )
```

Answer (score 5):

Try the `NTILE` function:

```
;WITH YourCTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        (some columns),
        percentile = NTILE(10) OVER(ORDER BY SomeColumn DESC)
    FROM
        dbo.YourTable
)
SELECT *
FROM YourCTE
WHERE percentile <= 4
```

The `NTILE(10) OVER(....)` creates 10 groups of percentages over your data - and thus, the top 40% are the groups no. 1, 2, 3, 4 of that result

Comment: `NTILE(10)` doesn't return the correct number of rows for a 15 row table. Redoing as `NTILE(5)` would reduce the problem but that still wouldn't return the correct number for a 7 row table.

Answer (score 5):

Use NTILE

```
CREATE TABLE  #temp(StudentID CHAR(3),  Score  INT)

INSERT #temp  VALUES('S1',75 )
INSERT #temp  VALUES('S2',83)
INSERT #temp  VALUES('S3',91)
INSERT #temp  VALUES('S4',83)
INSERT #temp  VALUES('S5',93 )
INSERT #temp  VALUES('S6',75 )
INSERT #temp  VALUES('S7',83)
INSERT #temp  VALUES('S8',91)
INSERT #temp  VALUES('S9',83)
INSERT #temp  VALUES('S10',93 )

SELECT * FROM (
SELECT NTILE(10) OVER(ORDER BY Score) AS NtileValue,*
FROM #temp) x
WHERE NtileValue <= 4
ORDER BY 1
```

Interesting enough I blogged about NTILE today: [Does anyone use the NTILE() windowing function?](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/does-anyone-use-the-ntile)

Answer (score 1):

Calculate and set ROWCOUNT for whatever number of records.
Then execute you query for the limited set.

```
declare @rc as integer
select @rc = count(*)*0.40 from CTE
Set ROWCOUNT @rc
select * from CTE
```

ROWCOUNT is not deprecated yet - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Using Top t-sql command:

```
select top 10 [Column_1],
[Column_2] from [Table]
order by [Column_1]
```

Using Paging method:

```
select 
[Column_1],
[Column_2]
from 
    (Select ROW_NUMBER() Over (ORDER BY [Column_1]) AS Row,
    [Column_1],
    [Column_2]
    FROM [Table]) as [alias]
WHERE (Row between 0 and 10)
```

This is finding the top 10 with order by [Column_1]...please note this is using [variable] method of documentation.

If you could provide column names and table names i could write much more beneficial t-sql, for example to find the top 40% you are going to need to do another sub-query to get count of all rows then do division, i'd likely do this as a query before i do the main query.